# Updating installed PWA

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular13

I installed a angular 13 pwa on Chrome in Android. I have the manifest and service worker on default and wanted to ask if there’s a way to force it to reload for an update I want to deploy? Now I know I should have used swUpdate or similar ways I should have thought about in advance but since I haven’t. Is there a way, besides waiting for the 24h automatic refresh of Chrome?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`ServiceWorkerRegistration` has an `update()` method you can [read about on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/update).